# Is there any solution to controls repeated properties?

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, properties, web-controls

Is there any solution to controls repeated properties ?

An example would be that imagine you have 4 gridview but each of them have the same templates, same properties, same everything (except id of course). It happened to me several times to have more than one gridview that have the same properties.. so i will ask my question again... **Is there any solution to controls repeated properties ?** and how to apply your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `UserControl` containing the control that you need to repeat and then the constructor for the `UserControl` to pass in the information that needs to be initialized.

Comment: I didn't think about this solution but this is a rather good solution. However at first i though skins would be used for this kind of task.

Comment: What would skins have to do with a repeated control? That's a style issue

Comment: Then this was a misunderstanding of what 'skins' are.. good then.

Comment: I definitely agree that usercontrols are suited to this task!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do and how your controls are populated. If I understand very well, you have duplicate gridviews. If that is the case then you can create your gridview dynamically in the code behind and populate it there through a function as you can see here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163612.aspx

If not please provide more details and I would be able to help.

Comment: +1 your answer are pertinent through i think an usercontrol will best fit my needs.